# Get NoData value of raster in pyqgis

Tags: raster, pyqgis, nodata

I'm fighting with pyqgis with a very simple issue.
I have a raster layer loaded in my TOC and I'd like to return with python its NoData value.

I looked in the API but (and sure it is my lack) I cannot find a way to do that.

So I get my raster as an object in the console:

```
rl = iface.activeLayer()
```

and I tried what I found in some websites (see the list at the bottom):

```
rl.getNoDataValue() #[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'getNoDataValue'


rl.noDataValue() #[2] old API
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsRasterLayer' object has no attribute 'noDataValue'
```

#[1]: http://qgis.sourceforge.net/qgis_api/html/classQgsRasterLayer.html#a10

#[2]: http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsRasterLayer.html#a558e7f4bb4abe6b95c6882fbe4d2e19f

Look into the `QgsRasterLayer` class `dir(rl)` but I cannot find a way to return the NoData values.

Comment: That method ('noDataValue') is in **QgsRasterBlock** class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That method ('noDataValue') is in **QgsRasterBlock** class (not in **QgsRasterLayer**). To get access to this method you can try out this code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
extent = layer.extent()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

rows = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
cols = layer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()

block = provider.block(1, extent,  rows, cols)

print block.noDataValue()
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks it works. I did not know that I can use this class to achieve the no data values.

Comment: in the new 3.x api you can get it directly from provider as documented in:
https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterDataProvider.html#a4fcc41a5e29c27c458d690f414dd9a40